# How do you make UIView's slide left to right and being butted right up against each other in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I've seen apps that have views that you swipe and it just slides to the next one, and it moves according to how far you've swiped.  Kind of like a film strip.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) to achieve precisely this effect. (Each "picture" in the film strip being a view that you add to the scroll view.)

Incidentally, the above linked class reference document also contains links to sample code - see the "Related sample code" section in the header.

**UPDATE**

Here's some sample code to detect the "current" page. It's been a while since I've used a UIScrollView (this is from an early "getting to know iOS" plaything I wrote), so this may not be the best solution.

```
// Calculate which page is visible  
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int currentPage = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
```

Comment: Got it.  But how do I know which is being shown at a given time?  Is there a better way than checking if a pixel from each of the views is showing?  And will this work with UIView's instead of UIImageView's?

Comment: @marty In the past I've calculated it based on the width of the frame and the current contentOffset in the scroll view itself. I'll update my question with some sample code.

Comment: It looks like setting pagingEnabled will make it snap.